# Add secret to projected list volume kustomize

Tags: kustomize

I am trying to use kustomize to patch existing Deployment by adding environment secrets in the list of projected

`deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: microservice-1
  name: microservice-1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: microservice-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: microservice-1
    spec:
      containers:
        image: URL
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: microservice-1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: http
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /config/secrets
          name: files
          readOnly: true
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: image-pull-secret
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: files
        projected:
          sources:
          - secret:
              name: my-secret-1
          - secret:
              name: my-secret-2
```

`patch.yaml`

```
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/0/projected/sources/0
  value: 
    secret: "my-new-secret"
```

`kustomization.yaml`

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
patchesJson6902:
- target:
    version: v1
    kind: Deployment  
    name: microservice-1
  path: patch.yaml
```

`Error`

```
Error: updating name reference in 'spec/template/spec/volumes/projected/sources/secret/name' field of 'Deployment.v1.apps/microservice-1.itc-microservices': considering field 'spec/template/spec/volumes/projected/sources/secret/name' of object Deployment.v1.apps/ms-pedigree.itc-microservices: visit traversal on path: [projected sources secret name]: visit traversal on path: [secret name]: expected sequence or mapping no
```

How can I add new secret to the list with key `secret` and field name:

```
- secret
    name: "my-new-secret"
```

NB: I have tried to to a PatchStrategic merge but the list is all remplaced.

Answer (score 0):

I have found.

```
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/0/projected/sources/-
  name: ok
  value:
    secret: 
      name: "my-new-secret"
```

Comment: Now how can i add a second secret ? Do I need to add a new "-op" block ? Or is there any tips to multiple item at once ?

Answer (score 0):

Your original deployment manifest has `sources` as an array. Notice the `-` character.

```
sources:
- secret:
    name: my-secret-1
- secret:
    name: my-secret-2
```

But your patches have different types:

Original patch.yaml `sources/0` is an array element, the value is supposed to be a map value named `name`, not `secret`. Notice the lack of a `-` character before the text `secret`. This is a map value, but the name key is missing, and the secret value would be added alongside `name`

```
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/0/projected/sources/0
  value: 
    secret: "my-new-secret"
```

This would result in:

```
sources:
- secret:
    name: my-secret-1
    secret: my-new-secret
- secret:
    name: my-secret-2
```

Not what you want.

Your second attempt changes the path to `/sources/-` but now you're trying to set `secret` as a map value, when it needs to be an array element because `sources` is an array:

```
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/0/projected/sources/-
  name: ok
  value:
    secret: 
      name: "my-new-secret"
```

This might work fine thanks to the `-` at the end of the path. Your next question is moot though. You can just simply do the exact same thing to add your next secret. The value of `-` in the `path` is always interpreted as the end of the array, so if you add a second whole block like below:

```
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/volumes/0/projected/sources/-
  name: ok
  value:
    secret: 
      name: "my-second-new-secret"
```

Then you should end up with:

```
sources:
- secret:
    name: my-new-secret
- secret:
    name: my-second-new-secret
```